# what is wrong with this scanner?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a scanner scan a txt file, when I have it scan 6 items in total (item is before and after "="), it works, when I have it scan more, it breaks. After scanning, I want the values to be returned to the main class.

```
public class mainClass {

public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            load loadery = new load("resources/monsters/human/humanSerf.txt");
            load.loader();
            String returned= loadery.retrn();
            System.out.println(returned);

     }
}
```

The scanner class:

```
public class load {
static String name, value,name1,value1,name2, value2,name3,value3,name4,value4,name5,value5;
  public static void loader(String... aArgs) throws FileNotFoundException {
    load parser = new load("resources/monsters/human/humanSerf.txt");
    parser.processLineByLine();
  }

  public load(String aFileName){
    fFile = new File(aFileName);  
  }


  public final void processLineByLine() throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(fFile));
    try {

        scanner.useDelimiter("=");

           name = scanner.next();
           value = scanner.next();
           name1 = scanner.next();
           value1 = scanner.next();
           name2 = scanner.next();
           value2 = scanner.next();
           name3 = scanner.next();
           value3 = scanner.next();
           name4 = scanner.next();
           value4 = scanner.next();
           name5 = scanner.next();
           value5 = scanner.next();

      ;

    }
    finally {

      scanner.close();
    }


     }


      // PRIVATE 
      private final File fFile;


      public static String retrn(){
      return name+"="+ value+"   "+name1+"="+ value1+"   "+name2+"="+ value2+"   "+name3+"="+ value3+"   "+name4+"="+ value4+"   "+name5+"="+ value5;
      }
      }
```

The txt file:

```
symbol=HS
strength=15
agility=13
constitution=7
wisdom=9
intelligence=5
```

What can I do to fix this?

These are the errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1347)

at load.processLineByLine(load.java:32)

at load.loader(load.java:8)

at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
scanner.useDelimiter( Pattern.compile("[\\r\\n= ]+") );
```